# The data types nvarchar(max) and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Tags: sql-server-2008, types

I am new to hibernate.
I have a scenario where i am using Xstream frame work to export the tables into XML format and importing another instance of DB tables, where i have my application with Hibernate & spring.

One instance where one column of a table is nvarchar(max) in the db.
while i am inserting into the table from xml, it is failinging giving below error.

Caused by:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The data types nvarchar(max) and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator.  
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)  
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)  
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)  
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:632)  
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:477)  
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery  (JtdsPreparedStatement.java:778)  
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery  (WrappedPreparedStatement.java:342)  
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getDatabaseSnapshot(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1021)  
at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.getDatabaseSnapshot(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:246)  
at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:189)  
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:512)  
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:80)  
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)  
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)  
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)  
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:495)  
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$18.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:772)  
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
```

I used the above mentioned provided solutions ...but none is of help for me.

i am using SQL 2008 server as DB and hibernate 3 jars.
It is working fine upto 4000 chars, but column exceeds it is not working.
and giving above exception

Please do advice how to solve this problem.